# How open just one connection to mongodb with mongoengine?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Currently I have a super simple function to open a connection with mongodb:

```py
from mongoengine import connect

connection = connect('<MY_DATABASE>')
```

I import the connection variable in all the files that need to make a transaction to the database. However, for each file a new connection to the database is opened, I want only 1 to be used in the entire application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that it imported and called the Config class in every file that needed to access the database. When it should only be imported into the composition root of the application.

Something like this:

```py
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import json

from routes.user_routes import user_router
from models.config import Config

Config.start_connection()
app = Sanic('TodoServer')

app.blueprint(user_router)

@app.route('/')
async def check_health(request):
    return json({ 'status': True, 'message': 'Server is up' });

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=3000, debug=True);
```